# PhoneGap DatePicker not working in iPad

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using Phonegap 2.2.0. I have added [the date picker plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins), but this plugin is not working in iPad, and working in iPhone.

Any ideas?

This is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the same behaviour on iPad V6 using Cordova/Phonegap 3.0.0 with the updated plugin javascript rewrite - did you manage to solve this issue??

Comment: Try this solution, it's nice. http://mobiscroll.com/

Comment: I've had a look at mobiscroll and it would solve our problem - but we have limited budget for this project :(

Comment: Why not use the native datepicker for ios?

Comment: mobiscroll is super easy to add into your project ;). I am very satisfied with this plugin...

Comment: @Bonnie Nah, we eventually used Shafi ps's suggestion i.e. Mobiscroll - it works great!

Answer (score 0):

There is another plugin which works for iPhone and iPad, including iOS 7 support: https://github.com/sectore/phonegap3-ios-datepicker-plugin